# Obtener la cantidad de comisiones a pagar en MySQL

Tags: mysql

como estan? Necesitaria obtener las siguientes cantidades:

Mostrar para cada contrato cantidad total de las comisiones, cantidad a pagar, cantidad a pagadas.

Las tablas son las siguientes:

Comisiones: nro_contrato(PK-FK de contratos), fecha_pago, importe_comision
Contratos: nro_contrato(PK), fecha_contrato.

Yo hice la siguiente consulta:

```
select cont.nro_contrato, count(*), if(com.fecha_pago is not null, 
  count(com.fecha_pago) , 0) as pagadas,
    if(com.fecha_pago is null, count(*), 0) as  a_pagar
    from contratos as cont inner join comisiones as com
        on cont.nro_contrato = com.nro_contrato
           group by cont.nro_contrato;
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si yo pido las comisiones, efectivamente en el contrato n° 1 por ejemplo, hay fecha_pago vacia, por lo que tendria que contar en a pagar, y no mostrar 0 como lo hace:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien me podria dar una mano? Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si intentas con UNIX_TIMESTAMP(fecha_pago) = 0 para contar los null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que buscas lo tienes que resolver dentro de la función `count()` no afuera, algo así:

```
select cont.nro_contrato, 
       count(*), 
       count(com.fecha_pago) , 0) as pagadas,
       count(case when com.fecha_pago is null then 1 else NULL end) as  a_pagar
       from contratos as cont inner join comisiones as com
            on cont.nro_contrato = com.nro_contrato
       group by cont.nro_contrato;
```

Es básicamente un recuento condicional, la condición la evaluas dentro dentro de la función de agregación mediante un `case`.

Comment: No me funciona, las a_pagar cuenta la misma cantidad que el count(*) general. Acabo de probar reemplazar el count por el sum en ese caso, con el case dentro y me funciona perfectamente! Muchas gracias!

Comment: Es cierto, un typo mio, arme el `case` para un `sum`, en el caso del `count` el retorno no debe ser 0 sino `null`. corregido.

Comment: Muchas gracias, te puedo hacer otra consulta que me surgio recien? Edito la pregunta, avisame, gracias!

Comment: @JuanAndressolanas, depende, si la pregunta va a cambiar mucho, tal vez sea preferible que hagas una nueva. ¿de que se trata?

Comment: Es sobre una funcion de grupo, mejor hago otra pregunta! Ya te paso el link

Comment: este es el link  : https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/329499/como-agrupar-registros-en-base-a-su-clave-primaria