# Como agrupar registros en base a su clave primaria

Tags: mysql

como estan ? Necesito hacer lo siguiente:

Mostar la cantidad de empresas diferentes que han realizado solicitudes y la diferencia respecto al total de solicitudes.

El problema es que no encuentro la forma de contar por separado las empresas que hicieron solicitudes(se que son 3). Las tablas son estas:

empresas: cuit(pk),razon social
solicitudes_empresas: cuit(pk - fk de empresas), cod_cargo.

Intente hacer tipo una consulta así:

```
     select count(select count(*) from solicitudes_empresas group by cuit) as 
     cantidad, (select count(*) from solicitudes_empresas) - (select count(*) from 
     solicitudes_empresas) as diferencia 
     from empresas as e 
     inner join solicitudes_empresas as sol 
     on e.cuit =  sol.cuit;
```

Pero no me funciona ya que me dice:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

y le estoy haciendo un count, asi que no se que sera! Muchas gracias!

Edit: Si hago lo siguiente:

```
select e.cuit  from empresas as e inner join solicitudes_empresas as sol
    on e.cuit = sol.cuit group by e.cuit;
```

Me devuelve efectivamente 3 registros:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero si a esa misma consulta le hago count(*) deberia devolverme el numero 3, pero me devuelve lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El error quiere decir que una o varias de esas subconsultas que tienes en el select estan devolviendo mas de un resultado y esto te va a generar error, deberias agregar una condición a las subconsultas para que muestren solo un resultado, prueba cada subconsulta, de una en una comenta o quita el codigo y  pruebas a ver cual es la que te da error

Comment: Si, ya me di cuenta eso recien porq las probe por separadas! Pero no se como hacer para que me de solo un resultado jeje

Comment: y cual es la que te da error ?

Comment: select count(*) from solicitudes_empresas group by cuit me devuelve 3 registros, yo necesitaria una forma de contar esos 3 registros y que me devuelva el numero 3, he intentado hacer count(..) de toda esa consulta pero no me deja por error de sintaxis y no encuentro el error.

Comment: Y si tratas de poner el count al Id de la tabla ? a ver si los cuenta.... y por que repites la consulta , me refiero a esto `(select count(*) from solicitudes_empresas) - (select count(*) from 
     solicitudes_empresas) as diferencia` tienes dos veces el mismo select

Comment: el primero le falta el group_by, se lo borre porq me daba error y no lo puse. Fijate que edite la pregunta y le agregue mas info

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104472/discussion-between-francisco-j-blanco-and-juan-andres-solanas).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La solución sería:

```
select count(empresaid) 
from (
select cuit empresaid, count(cuit) total 
from solicitudes_empresa 
group by (cuit)) subconsulta
```

La subconsulta te devolverá un registro por cada empresa que tiene una solicitud. La consulta externa te dará el conteo de estos registros.

Comment: Gracias, me sirvio tu respuesta!!